# Updating opencv to version 4.5.1

Tags: opencv

I need to update opencv to version 4.5.1 because there is a function that is not implemented in my current version 3.4.2. (I need to use the SIFT_create function, when I google a bit it seems that they removed it from 3.4.2 because of a patent. However, I have also heard from someone that this function has a different name in 3.4.2, so if you know this different name this is fine as well. I googled it but couldn't find anything about it.)

I tried updating opencv in the anaconda navigator but that didn't work. I tried typing

```
pip install opencv-python==4.0.0.21
```

(if I replaced 4.0.0.21 by 4.5.1 it couldn't find the version), but when I type

```
cv2.__version__
```

afterwards it still says I'm using version 3.4.2. I found this post: [How to upgrade OpenCV in Anaconda (windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873304/how-to-upgrade-opencv-in-anaconda-windows) which says I should use

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=4.3.0
```

I do this, both the exact same command and the command with 4.3.0 replaced by 4.5.1 but in both cases I only get version 4.0.0 (which apparently also doesn't have the SIFT_create function).

Any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I found the answer myself (or rather: with the help of non-internet people).

The problem was that while trying to update opencv, I ended up having two versions of opencv at once. I had opencv 4.5.1 and at the same time I had opencv-python 4.0.0.21 installed. When importing opencv, it chose to import opencv-python in stead of just opencv. When I deleted the opencv-python this fixed the problem.